# How realistic is the use of red yarn hub and spokes in crime television shows

Tags: analysis, realism, crime

I refer to a shot that occurs quite often in crime shows...

[image]

There is the victim at the hub and spokes of red yarn that connect the suspects. How realistic is this in modern detective work?

I have read these articles:

- [Decoding The Detective's 'Crazy Wall'](http://www.esquire.co.uk/culture/film/news/a7703/detective-show-crazy-walls/)
- [Do detectives really pin a bunch of pictures on a board when
  investigating a crime?](https://www.quora.com/Do-detectives-really-pin-a-bunch-of-pictures-on-a-board-when-investigating-a-crime)
- [What is the name of the evidence board used by Detectives?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-name-of-the-evidence-board-used-by-Detectives)
- [Does this investigative process have a name?](http://ask.metafilter.com/175282/Does-this-investigative-process-have-a-name)

All of which suggest **in a vague and noncommittal way** that this technique is more about narrative exposition for the television viewer rather than a detective's tool. Can someone confirm and explain?

Comment: Good question but the links you provided seem to answer it quite well.

Comment: I also like this question and am interested to see any answers, but a suggestion: if you consider the links you provided to be vague and non-committal, perhaps you could define the criteria for what you'd consider an authoritative answer?  ie: Do you want quotes from an actual homicide detective?

Comment: Links because it's good manners to demonstrate foundation research prior to posting a question on SO and not to waste member's time chasing down previously researched material. A live photo from inside 100 W. 1st St for example would be unassailable, right? or a similar attestation of impeccable credibility...

Comment: I'm confused by why your second link isn't an acceptable answer. It says sometimes police actually used to do this actual yarn, but now it's almost always done on a computer, and there is even at least one piece of software created specifically for this purpose. So it's 100% realistic but anachronistic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about crime solving rather than a movie or tv show.